# Program design when combining external sources with local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, architecture

I have a Rails app that is basically designed this way:

It has a Book model, that has an external_id (all saved Book records have an external_id). The external_id links to an external source about books that doesn't allow for the data to be stored. We use a Presenter to handle some of the differences in the Book model and the external library's class to smooth things over for the view.

We let users do things like "Favorite" their books, regardless of source, so we have a join table and model with a book_id and a user_id to record favorites.

However, in some of the queries, there will be a list of results displayed to the user from the external source, even though we might have Book records with those external_ids. We want to be able to display information like who that the user is friends with that has favorited that book.

It seems there are a couple of ways to handle this:

1) Always load the canonical Book record (if it exists) in the presenter based on the external_id, and override the Book#friends_who_favorited method to return false if no external_id was found

2) Overload the presenter to either call Book#friends_who_favorited or if not a Book record, create its own join query based on external_id (since we wouldn't know the book id yet).

3) Denormalize the database a little, and make sure that we always store the external_id everywhere -- Basically treat external_id like the primary key since every Book record has an external_id. Then the queries can be done more directly, not require a join query, and we wouldn't need multiple queries written. But, this ties us even more to that external source since now our database design will be based on external_id.

It seems like #1 might be the best way to do it, even though it would introduce an extra query to Book (Book.where(external_id: x).first), since #2 would require writing a whole set of additional queries to handle the external_id case. But, I'm open to suggestions as I'm not fully comfortable with any of these methods.

Comment: "We want to be able to display information like who that the user is friends with that has favorited that book." Dose this requirement has anything to do with external_id?

Comment: Yes, because when we display lists of books from the external source (such as a search), we still want to display that information.

Comment: Sorry I still don't understand why this is a problem. In my understanding, when user favourites a book, the only things make sense at that moment are user id and book id. There is no business of external_id. As for displaying the friends who liked this book, the logic should has nothing to do with external_id as well, because no matter the book is external or not you want to display that. This displaying logic can be a partial, a helper or a presenter method.

Comment: When the users search for books, the search queries the external source, so when the books are being listed on the search results page, we have only external_id, not the local book id. But we still want to display whether or not friends have favorited that book.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussions, if I do that I might consider this solution:

#### Setup

1. Uniform the identifier of all books to an id instead of ActiveRecord default id. This is the current field `external_id`, though I would prefer to rename it without underscore, say `rid` represents resource id.
2. Use a format for internal books on `rid` different from external books.

   For example, suppose the format of external id like "abcde12345", then you name the internal books rid as "int_123" according to actual id so all of them are guaranteed to be unique.
3. Use a model callback to update rid after creating. If it's internal, copy its id and add "int_" prefix. If it's external, save its external id to that field.

#### Usage

Now usage would be simpler. For every action, use `rid` instead of original id. When an  user favouring the book, the association would be the rid.

In the join table, you can also keep the original id there, so that when one day you changed implementation, there would still be original ids available.

Now the join table will have 4 fields: id, user_id, book_id(the original id), book_rid.

To display the users who liked this book, no matter the book is external or not, you can now query based on the rid in join table and fulfil the job.

#### Refacoring

Actually refacoring on this solution should not be hard and do no harm.

1. Add a field rid in the join table
2. Build a query task to fill rid of all books. Actually it's for internal books only which has blank external_id at this moment.
3. Build a query to fill the rid field in join table.
4. Refacor associating method to specify association id, and other related methods if needed.